# How can PTC resettable fuses (battery strap type) be mounted on PCB?

Tags: polyfuse

I need to use a resettable fuse in my design and I'm using something like this:

[image: Battery strap type resettable fuses]

Can strap type fuses be used on PCB and how can they be mounted on PCB?

Comment: Would it not be easier to simply select a PTC fuse designed for PCB mounting?   I can't see a reason why you can't form the leads of the part you show (perhaps make a tool for this), and design a suitable PCB land to accept it with hand soldering.  But in a production environment this part will just cause pain and cost as it's probably not supplied on a reel intended for pick and place machines.

Answer (score 1):

The flippant answer is sure, you can mount them on a PCB (or glue them to a marble bust of Julius Caesar) if you like.. but (there's almost always a 'but') they might not do what you want.

The PTC fuses are [temperature](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/datasheets/resettable_ptcs/littelfuse_ptc_sl_datasheet.pdf) and heat-loss sensitive. That's an advantage in a battery protection scheme (they "provide both over-current and over-temperature protection"), however by heat sinking the ends to a PCB you are going to radically increase the hold and break currents if the PCB itself is not getting hot.

SMT poly fuses are less straightforward to deal with than through-hole types because of the extra major variable (heat loss) and I'll hazard a guess that this would be much worse.